# Why in 3D game we need to separate a material into so many textures for a static object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js, textures, babylonjs

Perhaps the question is not that correct, the textures should be say a kind of channel? although I know they will be mixed in the shader finally.

I know the knowledge of the various textures is very important, but also a bit hard to understand completely.

From my understanding:

1. diffuse - the 'real' color of an object without light involved.
2. light - for static objects. render light effections into texture beforehand.
3. specular - the area where has direct reflection.
4. ao - to absorb indirect light for the different area of an object.
5. alpha - to 'shape' the object.
6. emissive - self illuminance.
7. normal - pixel normal vector to deal with the light ray.
8. bump - (dont' know the exact differences between normalmap).
9. height - stores Z range values, to generate terrain, modify vertex etc.

And the items below should be related to PBR material which I'm not familiar with:

- translucency / cavity / metalness / roughness etc...

Please correct me if some misunderstandings there.
But whatever, my question is why we need to separate these textures apart for a material but not only render them together into the diffusemap directly for a static object?

It'll be appreciated if some examples (especially for PBR) , and thank you very much.

Comment: Don't really get your question. You expect one slot to put all the different type of  textures?

Comment: I mean, for a static object, I can beforehand bake all things into the diffuse map and apply to my mesh, why I need to apply so many different textures?

Comment: *"bake all things into the diffuse map and apply to my mesh"* I don't think so. You would need to write a custom shader to do that. The standard one can't do that. See my answer

Comment: I've no idea what this question is supposed to be asking.

Comment: @SexyBoooom did you try baking all those things into a single texture? How would you bake your specular reflection, or any kind of reflection for that matter?

Comment: Other than these non-sensical combinations, baking lighting and diffuse or AO can totally work together.

Comment: @pailhead ah, I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can beforehand bake all things into the diffuse map and apply to my
>   mesh, why I need to apply so many different textures?

**Re-usability**:

Most games re-use textures to reduce the size of the game. You can't if you combine them together. For example, when you two similar objects but you want to randomize the looks of them(aging effect), you can make them share the-same color(albedo) map but use different ao map. This becomes important when there hundreds of objects, you can use different combination of texture maps on similar objects to create unique Objects. If you have combined this into one, it would be impossible to share it with other similar objects but you to slightly make to look different.

**Customize-able**:

If you separate them, you'll be able to change the amount of effect each texture will apply to the Object. For example, the slider on the metallic slot for the Standard shader. There are more of this sliders on other map slots but they only appear once you plug a texture into the slot. You can't do this when you combine the textures into one.

**Shader**:

The standard shader can't do this so you have to learn how to write shader since you can't use one image to get the effects you would with all those texture maps with the standard shader. A custom shader is required and you need a way to read the information about the maps in the combined shader.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the OP's confusion. Not sure what the standard shader (material?) has to do with this specifically (since there are listed maps from other materials too). Without knowing what happens in the shader this is hard to explain. Knowing how the shaders work, this is self-explanatory.

Comment: @pailhead *"Not sure what the standard shader (material?) has to do with this specifically (since there are listed maps from other materials too)"* A lot. The slots you see are actually from the shader not material. The material is reading the shader and  displaying the slots in the material. I am saying that the standard shader do not support what OP is trying to do and OP would have to write a custom shader to get this working

Comment: Right, but i think i'm saying that this still misses the original question. It's a bit more abstract than that - we're writing a shader, how do we write it so that reads everything from a single texture? Is it some kind of encoding, which would still unpack everything and use it as is, or what would the logic look like as if everything were baked?

Comment: I don't know where to start writing an answer for this. You can keep `metalness`, `roughness` and maybe `cavity` in one map. Trivial to create one, trivial to read it, but when it comes to compression, things are not so trivial any more etc. It's a pretty broad question.

Comment: `The slots you see are actually from the shader not material.` <- this is also misleading, these "slots" have nothing to do with the shaders, they are "properties" (javascript term) of a class, the class in this case being `THREE.StandardMaterial`. I'm not actually familiar with any "standard" shader within three.js, but there are templates for this particular sub class of `Material`. The "uniforms" that you are describing are only accessible to you if you use `Material.onBeforeCompile()` otherwise they only live in a cache inside of `THREE.WebGLRenderer`

Comment: ^ three.js under the hood interprets these properties and manages the shader uniforms, this is (for the most part) hidden from the user.

Comment: @pailhead Sorry, the shader part of this answer focuses on Unity3d not three.js. OP tagged Unity3d in this question first. My answer is based on Unity perspective not three.js. The slots are called properties in the shader. I called it slots since that's what it's called in Unity's Editor. They are part of Unity's shaderlab language and are programmed there. The materials reads the properties from the shader and displays them in the Editor also, you can read the properties from the material via code.

Comment: You are still wondering why I mentioned shader at-all, that's because it's complicated to extract each map values from one map and the standard shader does not support that so you will have to write your
own shader to get this working. This is one of the reasons *"why we need to separate these textures apart for a material"* so that we can use exiting standard material instead of spending time, writing shader code and testing it on all platforms to make sure they work. Imagine if you're just an artist, that's where it gets 
complicated.

Comment: Again, for the shader part of my answer, we *"separate these textures"* because it is more easier to code in shader with separate textures than with just one texture. Note that Shader is not the only thing mentioned in my answer. It's just part of the reason. OP made a comment under the questions that suggests he could just drop one texture there and it will work. I wanted to tell OP that this is not the case. More work needs to be done to get that working. Did you see the Re-usability and Customize-able section? Do they make sense to you?

Comment: Wow I didn’t even realize that this is tagged with a bunch of libraries. This question may simply be too broad.

Comment: @pailhead, Programmer    I'm sorry for the confusing about the question. What confused me is for example in a scene, there is no light and with only a cube box in it, is the OA map / light map useless now? so in such situation can I bake a direct image which has all things combined in it for my mesh's appereance? so which textures should be used to combine? I think I'm not quite understand about the effect of each textures affected by a light? and Programmer, your answer is what I originally want to know too.

Comment: AO/Occlustion map is different from a light map. To answer your question, you **still need** a light even with AO map. AO map is used to tell the model which part of the model receives more or less light from the light in the scene. Sometimes, you want a part of a model to receive more light than the other, this is what AO is used for. One example is cloth. See [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterOcclusionMap.html) post for example of model with and without occlusion.

Comment: [lightmaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/LightmappingInDepth.html)  is a whole different story. It let's bake the light in your scene into a proprietary Unity file format. This data includes the light and shadows in your scene. After baking lightmap, you can now delete the light if you wish and Unity will automatically load that saved light map data during runtime and use it as the light and shadow of your objects. The good part is that it **improves** performance a lot on mobile devices. The bad part is that the size of the lightmap is big increasing you app size.

Comment: I think that the emission map can be used to lighting the object even without light. If that's what you want, use an emission map. Now, you see what it's important to separate each map? By doing that, you have control on what the object should look like. I suggest you read and watch about texture maps in Unity [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/textures)  and the bottom of [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameters.html) page to understand all the maps in Unity and how they are read in Unity.

Comment: ah, so OA map still needs light, got it. for lightmap, you said I can delete the light, so you mean lightmap can be still visible even there is no light in the scene right?

Comment: Yup. It will re-create the light and shadwos with the data it saved on a file. You can delete the light's after that but you must bake the light map it via Unity. See [this](https://youtu.be/OVMnXB0NKfc?t=771) tutorial as this guy deletes the light after baking lightmap. The light is still there. Note that you can use the emission map to make object appear even without light but the downside is that it doesn't include shadow like light map. You can bake PBR  with lightmap and should do it on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a reasonable place to start:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping

> A texture map is an image applied (mapped) to the surface of a shape or polygon. This may be a bitmap image or a procedural texture. They may be stored in common image file formats, referenced by 3d model formats or material definitions, and assembled into resource bundles.

I would add to this that the shape or a polygon don't have to belong to 3d objects as one may imagine it. If you render two triangles as a rectangle, you can run all sorts of computations and store it in a "live" texture.

> Texture mapping is a method for defining high frequency detail, surface texture, or color information on a computer-generated graphic or 3D model. Its application to 3D graphics was pioneered by Edwin Catmull in 1974.

What this detail represents is either some agreed upon format to represent some property, (say "roughness" within some BRDF model) which you would encounter if you are using some kind of an engine.

Or whatever you decide that detail to be, if you are writing your own engine. You can decide to store whatever you want, however you want it.

You'll notice on the link that different "mapping" techniques are mentioned, each with their own page. This is the result of some person, or people who did some research and came up with a paper detailing the technique. Other people adopt it, and that's how they find their way into engines.

There is no rule saying these can't be combined.